# To disable compile , clean , validate test in maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am looking for ways to only run maven test phase, I tried this but it didn't work. Any pointers to fix this would help

```
mvn test -Dmaven.clean.skip=true -Dmaven.validate.skip=true -Dmaven.compile.skip=true
```

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what kind of problem you are trying to solve...

Comment: Your code and tests need compiled before you can actually run tests. Cleaning is optional, and validate phase runs after tests, anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `mvn surefire:test`, but it is recommended to run the other phases before.